# VS Code Remote - Can't run 'code' command in WSL Ubuntu 18 or WSL 2 Ubuntu 20 - wrong path

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2, vscode-remote

I'm having an issue when I try to run the `code` command from Visual Studio Code in WSL Ubuntu. I get the following error:

```
$ code .

/mnt/c/Users/Name/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.64.2/scripts/wslCode.sh: 63: /mnt/c/Users/Name/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.64.2/scripts/wslCode.sh: /home/barry/.vscode/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3/bin/remote-cli/code: not found
```

When I run the following, it installs the VS Code Server and the command works as expected:

```
$ /mnt/c/Users/Name/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/bin/code .
```

When I run `which -a code`, I can see I have two paths related to this command and I believe the correct one is `/mnt/c/Users/Name/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code`, but I don't know how to remove the first one or how it even related two paths to this command in the first place?

```
barry@RandomName:~$ which -a code
/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code
/mnt/c/Users/Name/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: happend to me as well just recently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to 'solve' it by creating a new Symlink to the correct directory so this one gets run first. I couldn't find a way to remove the incorrect directory so would appreciate it if someone knows a cleaner solution?

To add the Symlink, I ran `ln -s /mnt/c/Users/Name/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/bin/code /usr/local/bin/code`

So now I have these 3 paths for the code command:

```
$ which -a code

/usr/local/bin/code
/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code
/mnt/c/Users/Name/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code
```

Whenever I tried to remove `rm` or `unlink` `/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code` (with `sudo`), I get **permission denied**.

Answer (score 20):

Ran into the same problem 5 min ago and this post from thesteve0 worked for me:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6294#issuecomment-1031974516

Quoting from the original post:

1. Open VS Code on Windows
2. Open Extensions and then search on WSL
3. It should say the extension needs to be reloaded - go ahead and reload it
4. Open WSL and type code
5. This should force another upgrade of code and this time it should launch.

Comment: This worked for me as well - running ubuntu on wsl2, no systemd.

Answer (score 17):

I've had this issue and it was solved doing:

1. Open Terminal on Windows and Type `wsl`
2. You will be on the wsl env
3. Type `rm -rf ~/.vscode-server`
4. Type `logout` to leave the wsl env
5. Then type `wsl --shutdown`
6. Try to Open VSCode and connect with WSL.

Comment: This worked for me getting a format error: `Microsoft VS Code/bin/code: 61: /mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe: Exec format error`.

Comment: This also worked for me, thx @DavidR.Williamson for putting the Error I had in the comments!

Comment: @Joao Paul Dias, this solution worked for me, thank you!

Comment: Only solution that works for me, thank u @João Paulo Dias

Answer (score 4):

Just run Vscode normally on windows. This will load wsl extension and solve the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

A simple `sudo apt update -y` and then rerunning `code .` fixed this for me.

Comment: It works for me. Thank

Comment: it works for me too. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I ran into same error but any answer works for me until I saw this issue at github.

Make sure you don't use any software that depends on systemd, like snap, microk8s, etc.

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8952

Quoting from the original post:

"Disabling systemd support in /etc/wsl.conf resolves the issue."

/etc/wsl.conf (make sure you don't use any software that depends on systemd, like snap, microk8s, etc)

```
[boot]
#systemd = true
```

Just need to comment "systemd" and relaunch wsl

Comment: This caused my WSL instance to stop booting with a "The semaphore timeout period has expired" error.  (With error code Wsl/0x80070079).

Comment: do you use any software that depends on systemd?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, although I'm not certain how to tell, either. I was able to finally get in. I'm not sure whether it was due to me just waiting and relaunching the terminal after the wait or by accessing the `\\wsl$` share through Windows.

Comment: This can be a solution only if you tolerate the absence of systemd. Looks like a step back.
But the provided link was really helpful to me! There you could find a solution without compromises.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the extension in VS Code was not in a state needing reload like in [the most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71028287/320437). What helped after multiple attempts:

1. Terminate the WSL2 distribution (from the Windows CLI): `wsl -t Ubuntu` (replace `Ubuntu` with your distribution name)
2. Check that it is stopped: `wsl -l -v`
3. Start your WSL distribution again.

In my case the command `code` started to be accessible through a Windows directory: `/mnt/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my issue by opening wsl and removing the .vscode-server

`rm -rf .vscode-server`

i followed this link [link to fix](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4219)

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple S*upid method:

1. Download & install vscode again. [link for windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)

2. (Ubuntu example) `apt update && yes | apt upgrade`
3. Try to launch code from wsl

You should see something like:

```
Updating VS Code Server to version 5554b12acf27056905806867f251c859323ff7e9
Removing previous installation...
Installing VS Code Server for x64 (5554b12acf27056905806867f251c859323ff7e9)
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid using the Windows PATH in WSL. I added manual aliases to my `~/.bashrc`, e.g. for `code .`:

```bash
alias code='"/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code" .'
```

Answer (score 0):

In C:\Users<user>.vscode rename path ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl- to ms-remote-wsl-old

In WSL run: code .

Answer (score 0):

I got two versions of Visual Studio Code installed, one said "(user)". I uninstalled both and installed the newest version via winget.

That fixed it for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have got two different versions of visual studio code installed on my PC.
I have uninstalled the older version keeping the latest one.
This resolved issue for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

## **2023 Alpine linux on wsl is much simpler**

1. Open Terminal on Windows and Type and will be on the wsl env

```bash
wsl
```

2. Remove vscode server existing rm -rf ~/.vscode-server

```bash
rm -rf ~/.vscode-server
```

3. Type logout to leave the wsl env

```bash
logout
```

4. Shutdown wsl by command

```bash
wsl --shutdown
```

5. On vscode install wsl by searching WSL and also check terminal and you will see Wsl Alpine on dropdown or open cmd again as administrator and login to wsl.

```bash
wsl -d Alpine
```

6. Install drivers to connect with vscode

```bash
apk add libstdc++
```

7. Lastly navigate to project to open and type code. let say `/todo`

```bash
 /todo code .
```

8. You will see this on terminal meaning vscode has been installed for wsl alpine but I prefer using vscode teminal by just navigating on commandline wsl because it supports cross platform, wsl extension and procedure given above isolate wsl codes with local codes while opening.

```bash
Installing VS Code Server for Alpine (.....12d, linux-alpine)
Connecting to update.code.visualstudio.com (...ip here:443)
..................and the rest
```

! Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

My error was;
AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code: 61: /mnt/c/Users/****/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe: Exec format error

The answer from @pckben improved the situation for me and the above error stopped so I could start "code ." from WSL, but the vscode instance couldn't connect to the remote WSL.  Re-installing the WSL extension didn't help (no prompt to reload it).

Then I remembered I had run an update and ignored the "upgradeable" list.
I followed https://itsfoss.com/apt-list-upgradable/ and performed the "update" and the "upgrade" and that solved the problem for me.  It's possible clearing .vscode-server is also needed for a complete solution.